# How to get line number?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have developed a plugin to search the references of a method.I want to print out the line numbers where the method is referenced.I search for method going through IMethod class and check for a particular function reference.Now i want to print the line number.How can i do that?Help

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `ISourceReference` (http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/ISourceReference.html) object? It contains the source range, from which you could derive the line number, I guess.

Comment: @AndiDog: if you had put that in an answer, you would have gotten points...

Comment: @Stroboskop: Okay, added an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Okay so here's the answer from the comment... vote me up ;)*

You can use `ISourceReference` ([documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/ISourceReference.html)). It contains the source range, from which you could derive the line number.